# Meiler rails прикрепление файла

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

Все проблемы встречающиеся до этого исправил сам, наконец-то разобрался и понял механику. Вопросик заключается в том, а возможно ли прикрепить файл xls например к мейлеру rails или как можно передать файл с письмом в rails? 
Файл формируется с помощью rake.

Comment: Для начала, [прочитать гайды по теме](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#complete-list-of-action-mailer-methods).

Comment: @d-side  Tо что нужно. Уже работает и отсылает письма. спасибо